# Падает приложение при попытке регистрации Singleton'a в Prism

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, dependency-injection, prism

Раз за разом, когда пытаюсь выполнить регистрацию типа через `IContainerRegistry`, при создании экземпляра окна, падает приложение без какого либо оповещения, с исключением `StackOverflowException`.

Ниже представлен код класса `App`, все закомментированные строки, приводят к падению, причину которого мне выяснить не удалось, а так же не удалось посмотреть стек вызовов, дабы найти причину.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Используется `Unity`.*

Что может быть причиной, и что может помочь от него избавиться?

```
public partial class App
{
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IDleWebClient>(new DleWebClient());
        //containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton(typeof(DleWebClient));
        //containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IDleWebClient, DleWebClient>();
        //containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IDleWebClient), typeof(DleWebClient));
        //containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IDleWebClient), typeof(DleWebClient), "DleWebClient");
    }
}
```

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IDleWebClient _dleWebClient;
    private string _title = "Prism Application";

    public MainWindowViewModel(IDleWebClient dleWebClient)
    {
        _dleWebClient = dleWebClient;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get => _title;
        set => SetProperty(ref _title, value);
    }
}
```

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IDleWebClient _dleWebClient;
    private string _title = "Prism Application";

    public MainWindowViewModel(IDleWebClient dleWebClient)
    {
        _dleWebClient = dleWebClient;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get => _title;
        set => SetProperty(ref _title, value);
    }
}


public class DleWebClient : IDleWebClient
{
    private readonly CookieContainer _cookies;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    private readonly string _userDocumentsDirectory =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments,
            Environment.SpecialFolderOption.Create);

    public DleWebClient() : this(new Uri(Resources.AniDUB_BaseAddess))
    {
    }

    public DleWebClient(Uri siteAddress)
    {
        _cookies = TryLoadCookies();

        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseCookies = true,
            AllowAutoRedirect = true,
            MaxAutomaticRedirections = 10,
            CookieContainer = _cookies
        };

        _httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler, true)
        {
            BaseAddress = siteAddress,
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0D)
        };
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public bool LogoutUser()
    {
        return LogoutUserAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }

    public async Task<bool> LogoutUserAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage message = await _httpClient
            .GetAsync(new Uri(Resources.AniDUB_Action_Logout, UriKind.Relative), cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            bool result = message.IsSuccessStatusCode;
            CookieCollection collection = _cookies.GetCookies(_httpClient.BaseAddress);
            return collection
                       .Cast<Cookie>()
                       .Any(cookie =>
                           cookie.Name.Equals(Resources.AniDUB_Cookies_Id,
                               StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                           cookie.Name.Equals(Resources.AniDUB_Cookies_Password,
                               StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) ||
                   result;
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> AuthUserAsync(string userLogin, string userPwd,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage message = await _httpClient.PostAsync(
            new Uri(Resources.AniDUB_Index, UriKind.Relative),
            new UserLoginInfo(userLogin, userPwd).ZipToSend(), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            message.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            CookieCollection collection = _cookies.GetCookies(_httpClient.BaseAddress);
            return collection
                .Cast<Cookie>()
                .Any(cookie =>
                    cookie.Name.Equals(Resources.AniDUB_Cookies_Id,
                        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                    cookie.Name.Equals(Resources.AniDUB_Cookies_Password,
                        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        }
    }

    public bool AuthUser(string userLogin, string userPwd)
    {
        return AuthUserAsync(userLogin, userPwd)
            .ConfigureAwait(false)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }

    public async Task<string> LoadPageStringAsync(uint pageId)
    {
        return await _httpClient
            .GetStringAsync(new Uri(string.Format(Resources.AniDUB_Request_Page, pageId), UriKind.Relative))
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public string LoadPageString(uint pageId)
    {
        return LoadPageStringAsync(pageId)
            .ConfigureAwait(false)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }

    public async Task<Stream> LoadPageStreamAsync(uint pageId)
    {
        return await _httpClient
            .GetStreamAsync(new Uri(string.Format(Resources.AniDUB_Request_Page, pageId), UriKind.Relative))
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public Stream LoadPageStream(uint pageId)
    {
        return LoadPageStreamAsync(pageId)
            .ConfigureAwait(false)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }

    private CookieContainer TryLoadCookies()
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(_userDocumentsDirectory, Resources.AniDUB));
        string cookiesPath = Path.Combine(_userDocumentsDirectory, Resources.AniDUB, Resources.AniDUB_Cookies_Name);
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        if (File.Exists(cookiesPath))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Resources.Info_HaveCookies, Resources.Info, DateTime.Now);
            using (FileStream fileCookies =
                File.Open(Path.Combine(cookiesPath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(fileCookies) as CookieContainer;
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(Resources.Warning_NoCookies, Resources.Warning, DateTime.Now);
        using (FileStream cookies = File.Create(cookiesPath))
        {
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(cookies, new CookieContainer());
            return new CookieContainer();
        }
    }

    private void SaveCookies()
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(_userDocumentsDirectory, Resources.AniDUB));
        string cookiesPath = Path.Combine(_userDocumentsDirectory, Resources.AniDUB, Resources.AniDUB_Cookies_Name);
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        if (!File.Exists(cookiesPath)) return;
        Debug.WriteLine(Resources.Info_SaveCookies, Resources.Info, DateTime.Now);
        using (FileStream fileCookies =
            File.Open(Path.Combine(cookiesPath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(fileCookies, _cookies);
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseUnmanagedResources()
    {
        _httpClient?.Dispose();
    }

    ~DleWebClient()
    {
        SaveCookies();
        ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
    }
}
```

Comment: Трассировка стека? Код для `DleWebClient`?

Comment: Точку останова в конструкторе `DleWebClient` ставили? Какой из конструкторов используется?

Comment: @tym32167, ставил, конструктор не вызывается, т.к. дело не доходит до инициализации `ViewModel`'и, т.к. тип будет создан только когда он понадобится.

Comment: я и не говорю про `ViewModel`, я говорю про `DleWebClient`

Comment: @tym32167, я понимаю, я вам про `DleWebClient` и говорю, не доходит до вызова консрукторов.

Comment: попробуйте оставить у `DleWebClient` один пустой конструктор

Comment: Убрал вызов `this(...)` ничего не изменилось, так же не доходит до вызова конструктора, и падает.

Comment: уберите вообще вот этот конструктор `DleWebClient(Uri siteAddress)`. И пожно поглядеть на всю настройку контейнера?

Comment: Хм, когда остался один конструктор, все успешно запустилось... Это довольно странно как по мне.

Comment: ну а теперь добавляйте по строчке кода и найдете причину

Comment: я думаю, что проблема в `public DleWebClient(Uri siteAddress)` в `Uri` - оно автоматом не может разрезолвиться, вам надо явно прописать, какой `Uri` вы хотите или явно прописать, чтобы вызывался конструктор без параметров.

Comment: Да, так и есть, думаю буду писать баг репорт, или же что бы была добавлена перегрузка для указания ссылки на уже созданный экземпляр, т.к. сейчас такое невозможно с версией `7.2.x.x`.

Comment: Какой именно баг репорт? Вы указали 2 конструктора, юнити выбрала сама один из них. Если для вас это не сратабывает, то надо явно указывать, какой конструктор юзать, или явно указывать значение параметра `container.RegisterSingleton<IDleWebClient, DleWebClient>(new InjectionConstructor(new Uri("http://google.ru")));`, тут нет никакого бага, вы сами себе сделали больно :)

Comment: `или же что бы была добавлена перегрузка для указания ссылки на уже созданный экземпляр` вот же она `containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IDleWebClient>(new DleWebClient());`, точнее вот так `container.RegisterInstance<IDleWebClient>(new DleWebClient(), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());` ([docs](https://unitycontainer.github.io/api/Unity.Lifetime.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager.html))

Comment: @tym32167, добавьте последний комментарий ответом с ссылкой на документацию. Я и не знал что так можно регистрировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример регистрации синглтона при наличии ссылки на объект

```
container.RegisterInstance<IDleWebClient>(new DleWebClient(), 
                         new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

[Документация](https://unitycontainer.github.io/api/Unity.Lifetime.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager.html) по времени жизни синглтона.