# Prism.WPF & DryIoc, как регистрировать типы с фабрикой?

Tags: c#, wpf, inversion-of-control, prism

Доброго времени суток.
Возникла проблема с регистрацией типов в IContainerRegistry с фабрикой.
Могу регистрировать так:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<Config>();
```

А нужно что-то подобное:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<Config>(Config.Load);
```

Пробовал ставить пакеты: Prism.DryIoc.Extensions и Prism.Container.Extensions, результата ноль, только ошибка
StackTrace:

```html
System.NotImplementedException
  HResult=0x80004001
  Сообщение = Метод или операция не реализована.
  Источник = Prism.Container.Extensions
  Трассировка стека:
   в Prism.Ioc.IExtendedContainerRegistryExtensions.RegisterSingletonFromDelegate(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry, Type serviceType, Func`1 factoryMethod)
   в Prism.Ioc.IExtendedContainerRegistryExtensions.RegisterSingletonFromDelegate[T](IContainerRegistry containerRegistry, Func`1 factoryMethod)
   в Malinka.App.RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry) в C:\Users\Alexandr\source\repos\Malinka\Malinka\App.xaml.cs:строка 34
   в Prism.PrismApplicationBase.Initialize()
   в Prism.PrismApplicationBase.InitializeInternal()
   в Prism.PrismApplicationBase.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
   в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   в System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   в System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   в MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   в MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   в System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   в MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   в MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   в System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   в System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   в System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   в System.Windows.Application.Run()
   в Malinka.App.Main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же пробовал с Prism.Unity, но выходит какой-то страшный код:

```
var container = containerRegistry.GetContainer();
container.RegisterFactory(typeof(Config), null, (_, __, ___) => Config.Load(), new SingletonLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: Есть трассировка стека?

Comment: Да: https://pastebin.com/ZWNy0SEx

Comment: в вопрос, всё добавляйте в вопрос

Comment: в ошибке `NotImplementedException` вы поняли, какой именно метод не реализован?

Comment: текст трассировки в вопрос, не ссылку :)

Comment: Суть в том, что метод то реализован, но для не для стандартного контейнера: https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Container.Extensions/blob/f5a72a4b4fca1d02d285fd8a37883a98bd23e15e/src/Prism.Container.Extensions/IExtendedContainerRegistryExtensions.cs#L95

Comment: то есть вам надо что что то [типа этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7576856/312041)?

Comment: Да, верно, но нужен еще и Singleton, а так же лучше для DryIoc,  а не для Unity

Comment: У меня где-то был такой вопрос... И был ответ.

Comment: @ヒミコ вот будет забавно, если еще и я на него отвечал :))

Comment: Не уверен то ли это, но вроде бы то что нужно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1026736/206435

Comment: Это для Unity :(

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
using DryIoc;
...
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterDelegate(x => Config.Load(), Reuse.Singleton);
}
```